# Magento 2 : How To Add Custom Images To More Views of Product in Frontend

Tags: magento2, product-images

I am working on custom extension, and need to override more views section of the product. By overriding this block I need to add some additional images with product default images in more views.

How can I do this? Any Example?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I get the solution in another way.

We can do this using magento 2 plugin functionlity. 
For that you need to do following.

In di.xml file specify plugin like this.

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery">
        <plugin name="plugin_block_catalog_product_view_gallery"
                type="[Company]\[Vendor]\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Gallery"
                sortOrder="10"
                disabled="false"/>
 </type>
```

You need to do code in this file [Company][Vendor]\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Gallery.php